# Ternary operator with return statements JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ternary

I need to return true or false if an option in a drop down selected.

This is my code:

```
var active = sort.attr('selected') ? return true : return false;
```

I get an error that the first `return` is unexpected.

Why?

Comment: The *conditional* operator requires expressions, not statements. `return sort.attr("selected") ? true : false`. Or just do `return !!sort.attr("selected");`

Comment: Since the selected **property** is boolean, far better to do: `return sort.selected`

Comment: @RobG: `sort` appears to be a jQuery object.

Comment: Then `sort.prop(selected)` is more likely to be what is required.

Comment: Actually, `sort` is a Cheerio object. I'm working on some Node.js server side stuff and we use Cheerio instead of jQuery. They share many of the same functions and act similar but Cheerio is a lot slimmer and faster because it leaves out a lot of the DOM manipulation methods. `prop` would probably work had I been using jQuery, sadly, it does not. :(

Answer (score 55, accepted):

You cannot assign a return statement to a variable. If you want `active` to be assigned the value `true` or `false`, just delete the `return`s:

```
var active = sort.attr('selected') ? true : false;
```

or maybe better:

```
var active = sort.prop('selected');
```

since `.prop` always returns `true` or `false`, regardless of the initial tag attribute.

Comment: Since the jQuery *attr* method returns either a string or undefined (which is inconsistent with the W3C DOM *getAttribute* method that always returns a string) it may be better to test the actual returned value rather than rely on boolean conversion.

Comment: Yes. I've simplified my response to what I think OP really wants to know.

Answer (score 166):

You can return from a ternary operator in javascript like this:

```
return sort.attr('selected') ? true : false;
```

Comment: Technically correct and an answer to OP's question but not what OP actually needed :-)

Comment: But perfect answer for people coming in from Google ;)

Comment: This answer should be accepted >_<

Comment: Coming from Google, I was looking to see if it's possible to return only in the negative case. I.e. assign a true value or return false.

Answer (score 12):

why not just this?

```
 return sort.attr('selected');
```

Answer (score 6):

From the docs:

> **Syntax**
>   `condition ? expr1 : expr2`
>   **Parameters**
>   condition (or conditions)
>   An expression that evaluates to true or false.
>   **expr1, expr2**
>   Expressions with values of any type.

You should pay attention to the `Expressions with values of any type`., the `return xxx` is not an expression.

From wikipedia:

> An expression is a syntactic construct, it must be well-formed: the allowed operators must have the correct number of inputs in the correct places, the characters that make up these inputs must be valid, have a clear order of operations, etc. Strings of symbols that violate the rules of syntax are not well-formed and are not valid mathematical expressions.

So, in your case you can use:

```
return sort.attr('selected') ? true : false
```

Answer (score 2):

Just a comment on your code:

```
> sort.attr('selected')
```

seems to be using the jQuery [*attr*](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) method, which used to try and second guess what you wanted and return either the attribute or the property. I think in recent versions it returns the attribute always.

Anyway, the presence of the *selected* attribute only means that the item (an option element?) is the **default** selected option, it doesn't mean that it is the **currently** selected option. For that you need the selected **property** (jQuery [*prop*](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) method). And since the *selected* property is a boolean:

```
> sort.attr('selected') ? true : return false;
```

can simply be:

```
 sort.prop('selected');
```

or without jQuery:

```
 optionElement.selected;
```