# Java Ternary Operator Error

Tags: java, ternary

1. `Errors are illegal start of an expression`
2. `error: not a statement`
3. `';' expected`

I am receiving an error about my if else statement in takeStix().

```
private int numStix;

public int getNumStix() {return numStix;}

public boolean takeStix(int number) {
      ( number <= 3 && number <= getNumStix() ) ? return true : return false;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't put statements (like `return true`) in the ternary operator, only values.

So you could put:

```
return (number <= 3 && number <= getNumStix()) ? true : false;
```

But you don't even need a ternary operator for this:

```
public boolean takeStix(int number) {
    return (number <= 3 && number <= getNumStix());
}
```

Comment: Is this a Java only rule?  I tend to do this in my JavaScript is this a bad practice?

Answer (score 1):

In your case, as @khelwood has shown, you don't need a ternary expression. In general, however, the format for using a ternary expression in a return statement should be

```
return boolean_condition ? something : something_else
```

For example,

```
public boolean takeStix(int number) {
    return number <= Math.min(3, getNumStix()) ? true : false;
}
```

Comment: Thank you that makes more sense.

Comment: Is this a Java only rule?  I tend to do this in my JavaScript is this a bad practice?

Comment: In general, it is a better practice to avoid ternary expressions when a simple boolean assignment suffices. I am no expert in JavaScript, but this discussion might be useful for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19439219/ternary-operator-with-return-statements-javascript

Comment: Ahhh I understand it now.  Since the condition itself is a Boolean it will generate true or false regardless.  Thank you, this will help my programming tremendously.